# Right Way to validate form input fields

Tags: php, laravel, api, validation, laravel-5.3

I'm building an API, one of the db table `Person` have 52 columns and most of them are required t don't think the way I'm doing is right

```
public function store() {
    if (! input::get('name') or ! input::get('age') or ! input::get('phone') or ! input::get('address') and so on till the 52 field) {
        return "Unprocessable Entity";
    }

    return "Validated";
}
```

And how to properly validate all the required fields

Thank You

Comment: Simply go through validation class of laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia   thank you for your response, i did go through     $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

Comment: So whats the issue

Comment: i just wan to know is there any better way to do

Comment: Simply create a `ValidationRequest` file for the same and write you logic within that one.

Comment: I think it is better to use a front end form validator like jquery validator plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write your validation rules and messages within a Request file and can call directly within your `store` function like as

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

/**
 * Class YourFileRequest
 * @package App\Http\Requests
 */
class YourFileRequest extends Request
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
           'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255', 
           'body' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the custom validation messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
           'title.required' => 'Please enter title', 
           'title.max' => 'Please enter max value upto 255', 
           'body.required' => 'Please enter body',
        ];
    }

}
```

within your controller

```
use App\Http\Requests\YourFileRequest;


......


public function store(YourFileRequest $request) 
{
    //Your storing logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1. The first one is

   ```
   $this->validate($request,['email'=>'required|email|unique']);
   ```
2. Secondly, you can create a separate ValidationRequest by using the following command:

   ```
   php artisan make:request StoreRequest
   ```